# AWS Elasticsearch authorization header

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, hash

I'm attempting to make a request to the search API on AWS elasticsearch. My request works when the cluster is open. When I limit access to the cluster and try to generate a signed request, it fails with a 403 Forbidden error. I've narrowed down the error to the payload hash generated by my request. My request body is as follows:

```
{
"query" : {
"bool" : {
  "must" : [
    {
      "exists" : {
        "field" : "part3",
        "boost" : 1.0
      }
    }
  ],
  "filter" : [
    {
      "term" : {
        "part1" : {
          "value" : "v",
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "disable_coord" : false,
  "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
  "boost" : 1.0
}
},
"aggregations" : {
"uniqueLabels" : {
  "terms" : {
    "field" : "labelKeyword",
    "size" : 20,
    "min_doc_count" : 1,
    "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
    "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
    "order" : [
      {
        "_count" : "desc"
      },
      {
        "_term" : "asc"
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "pageViews" : {
      "sum" : {
        "field" : "count"
      }
    },
    "count" : {
      "value_count" : {
        "field" : "labelKeyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

I obtained this JSON using the `ElasticSearch SearchSourceBuilder.toString()`
How does the payload hash need to be generated? I'm using:

`Hashing.sha256().hashString(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString();`

from the Guava library.

The hash that AWS is expecting for this body is different from the one I'm generating. Is there some encoding that needs to be done to generate the right hash?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for similar thing few month back. I found a repo and did some minor tweaks. This code submits a properly signed request to AWS ES service. Please find the source at https://github.com/dy10/aws-elasticsearch-query-java

Its tough to get the V4 signing right if you are trying to implement it on your own!

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/inreachventures/aws-signing-request-interceptor. I was using the Jest client library for ES so this worked out well.